# Handling Awesomium ShowCreatedWebView Event in a Console headless browser

Tags: c#, awesomium, headless-browser

I have a working headless browser built with c# and the Awesomium.Core for .NET.

I'm trying to handle the `ShowCreatedWebView` of the main view to catch new WebView and load them into the main one.

In the [documentation](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowCreatedWebView) of `ShowCreatedWebView` the Example is using the WinForm Control which I'm not using:

```
internal static void OnShowNewView( object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e )
{
    WebControl webControl = sender as WebControl;

    if ( webControl == null ) return;

    if ( !webControl.IsLive ) return;

    ChildWindow newWindow  = new ChildWindow();

    // ....
```

My Question is - How can I create the new Child window and load it into the main view using only the Awesomium.Core?

In the documentation they mentioned that for Awesomium.Core you should:

- Pass NewViewInstance to WebView(IntPtr) to wrap the new view with a WebView.
- For windowed views (see ViewType), you should now assign a ParentWindow. Offscreen views have a BitmapSurface assigned by default but depending on your application's design, you may have to assign a new ISurface by either monitoring the CreateSurface event, or setting the Surface property.
- Resize the WebView to match its container.

I did that:

```
webView = new WebView(e.NewViewInstance);
webView.Resize(1024, 768);
```

It seems to load a blank page without the URL or the Post Data ... In my case I expect a `onDownload` Event to be fired after loading the new View.

I suspect I'm not handling the new View correctly any Ideas?